# append row with date in Google Sheet using Google Apps Scripts and retain date formatting specified in sheets

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, format

I have a column in my sheet with a custom date format. The format is set on the entire column. If put a date value in the column from within sheets it shows formatted the way I specified. But if I append a new row using Google Apps Scripts it will not obey the formatting.

Before adding a row through Google Apps Script:

```
| Timestamp                 | Message |
|---------------------------|---------|
| 2019-01-01 @ 13:12:32.013 | test    |
```

After adding a row:

```
| Timestamp                 | Message |
|---------------------------|---------|
| 2019-01-01 @ 13:12:32.013 | test    |
|         1/2/2019 14:51:31 | test2   |
```

Google Apps Script code to add the row:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([new Date(), "test2"])
```

Is there a way to get the date to be added in a way Sheets will format it per the formatting rule?

The only way I have found is converting the data to an integer representing the number of days since 1899-12-30 but this seems very hacky.

```
var dateSerial = ((new Date()) - (new Date(1899, 11, 30))) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Comment: Have you tried setNumberFormat()?  or possibliy Utilities.formatDate()?

Comment: Both of those would require setting the format from the JavaScript. If the format in the Sheet is changed then I'll have to update the code. I want to be able to change the format in the sheet, when/if needed, without having to update the code.

Comment: I guess were just different. I prefer doing it in the code.

Comment: @Cooper I'm writing the code, someone else will use the sheet. I don't want the code to break when/if they change the date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cooper mentioned in his comment, you can achieve this with `Utilities.formatDate()`.

I tested with the below script and the date format comes out exactly as you want it.

```
function addDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd @ hh:mm:ss.SSS');
  sh.appendRow([d,'test']);
}
```

All you really need to be interested in is `var d` where the date is defined. I used the Spreadsheet timezone for this but you can use any time zone you'd like.

```
var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd @ hh:mm:ss.SSS');
```

**Edit:**

User does not want to set date format in the script itself, instead we can grab the number format from the column above using `getNumberFormat()` and then format the new entry based on this, using `setNumberFormat()`.

See script below for details.

```
function setDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();

  //get format for last row in column A
  var format = sh.getRange(lr, 1).getNumberFormat();

  //add new data to sheet
  sh.appendRow([new Date(), 'test']);

  //format new data
  sh.getRange(lr+1, 1).setNumberFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: This requires me to set the format in the Javascript. See my reply to Cooper above.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I've just edited the answer with a solution that should satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I will see how this works. I want to see what would be more efficient, pulling the data format and then re-setting or just adding the value as a `dateserial`. Thanks!